# MSIX Installer with License Agreement

Tags: msix

When you install the MSI Installer, mostly the license agreement dialog will pop up,

Like this one.

https://winscp.net/eng/data/media/screenshots/installer_license.png

I converted the MSI installer to MSIX package format. I used the MSIX packaging tool. However, when I install the MSIX the license agreement doesn't show.
Is there a way to show the license agreement in the MSIX package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of AppX(now called MSIX) packages, back in Windows 8, Microsoft released new guidelines for application configuration.

For all apps installed through an AppX/MSIX package, the user configurations will take place the first time the app is launched by the user. This means the installation UI can no longer be customized to gather user input (or display info like the EULA) and execute your own code to prepare the app before the first launch.

Microsoft recommends for all this to be done from inside your app, decoupling the install phase from the initial configuration of the app.

For enterprise deployment, were end-users usually expected their apps to be pre-configured and ready to work with, the IT departments will be able to use [MSIX modification packages](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-modification-package-introduction.html) to include next to the app the additional configurations required (eg. a license file, default homepage in a browser, and so on etc.).

Subscribe